# Loading and rendering shapefile in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I wanted to know how qgis reads shapefile. Like i have choose any shapefile from qgis dialog then what are the steps that qgis take to read and render this shapefile data. 
Wrather it reads full shapefile data into memory or it opens file connection and reads and renders at runtime?

So far i have found this

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, name, provider)
if not layer.isValid():
  raise IOError, "Failed to open the layer"

# add layer to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# set extent to the extent of our layer
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())

# set the map canvas layer set
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
```

I have opened documentation of each function but i am not successfull in understanding flow of how it is reading shapefile

Answer (score 3):

Check the [PyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html) for code samples like this

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer name you like", "ogr")
if not layer:
  print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Comment: i have seen it but i am more interested about this addvectorLayer function like i wanted to know how this is reading file weather it is storing full file in local memory or it is reading at runtime

Comment: and i also wanted to know how qgis is reading layer like how ot is reading each item in layer and then drawing it on map

Comment: i wanted to know this because when i load file of 400mb in qgis then qgis memory doesnot increase accordingly so i think qgis is not loading file in memory